# Form/connection breaks after dynamic dropdown from database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

I have a dynamic dropdown list that gets records from a database and shows them as options.

This works on 2 different places but now I am trying to use it somewhere else and it somehow disconnects from my database and the rest of the form beneath it isn't showing.

This is the form part where I try to use it:

```
<label for="postcode">
Postcode:

    <select name="postcode" required>
        <option selected disabled value="<?php echo $postcode_result['postcode'] ?>">
            <?php echo $postcode_result['postcode']; ?> - <?php echo $postcode_result['adres']; ?> - <?php echo $postcode_result['woonplaats']; ?>
        </option>
        <?php     
        selectPostcodeOptions($conn);
        ?>
    </select>
```

And this is the `selectPostcodeOptions()` function that gets all options and places them as the select options:

```
    function selectPostcodeOptions($conn) 
    {
        $postcode_query = "SELECT * FROM postcodes
                            ORDER BY postcode"; 
    
        $postcode_result = $conn->query($postcode_query);
        if (!$postcode_result) die ("<span style='color:red'>" . "Kon geen gegevens van de database ophalen. 
                                        Klik a.u.b. op het pijltje terug in de browser en probeert u het opnieuw" . "</span>");
    
        $num_postcodes = $postcode_result->num_rows;
    
        for ($p = 0; $p < $num_postcodes; ++$p) {
            $row = $postcode_result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    
            $postcode = htmlspecialchars($row['postcode']);
            $straat = htmlspecialchars($row['adres']);
            $woonplaats = htmlspecialchars($row['woonplaats']);
    
            echo "<option value='$postcode'>" . $postcode . " - " . $straat . " - " . $woonplaats . "</option>"; 
        } 
    
        $postcode_result->close();
    }
```

Like I said, the function inside a `<select>` dropdown works on 2 different places (1 is on the same page) but this one gives me the error after die() and the 2 textarea form fields aren't showing...

This might be something really simple I am not seeing but I can't figure it out whatever I do...

(this below is the same drop down list on the same page. Difference is that I don't have an option pre selected. When I remove the function `selectPostcodeOptions` from the not working dropdown and just fill in some random options it works.)

```
<label for="postcode">
    Postcode:
    <select name="postcode" required>
        <option disabled selected value>------</option>
        <?php     
        selectPostcodeOptions($conn);
        ?>
    </select>
</label>
```

Anyone has any guess what I am overlooking? if more info is needed I will edit my question.

Comment: What error are you getting? Use `$conn->error` to get the MySQL error message.

Comment: If I place $conn->error inside the function after $postcode_result = $conn->query($postcode_query);  and I inspect the page it gives me the text "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now. other than this I don't get an error

Comment: That IS the error.

Comment: Search SO for that error mesage to find out how to fix it.

Comment: Feeling stupid now. Thanks for the pointer and I will try to fix this!